# JavaScript Countdown timer not starting [Firebug error included]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have this countdown timer on my page: http://www.dirtycookie.co.

It does not countdown unless you refresh the page.

I have the same script working a little differently @ [m.dirtycookie.co](http://m.dirtycookie.co) for reference.

I have this script on my index.php `<head>`

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

        function countdown() {
        // input new date here
        var newdate = new Date("Mar 01, 2013 20:00:00");
        // input new date here

        //DO NOT TOUCH THE REST UNLESS YOU KNOW JQUERY WELL
        var now = new Date();
        var timeDifference = newdate.getTime() - now.getTime();
        var d = Math.floor(timeDifference / 1000);
        var l = Math.floor(d / 60);
        var b = Math.floor(l / 60);
        var u = Math.floor(b / 24);
        b %= 24; l %= 60; d %= 60;

        if(d < 0){ var d = 0}
        if(l < 0){ var l = 0}
        if(b < 0){ var b = 0}
        if(u < 0){ var u = 0}

        $(".days").html(u);
        $(".hours").html(b);
        $(".minutes").html(l);
        $(".seconds").html(d);

        var timer = setTimeout('countdown()',1000);
        //DO NOT TOUCH THE REST UNLESS YOU KNOW JQUERY WELL
    }
window.onload=countdown ; 
});
</script>
```

THe firebug error:
ReferenceError: countdown is not defined
http://www.dirtycookie.co/
Line 106
Line 106 is actually: `var timer = setTimeout('countdown()',1000);`

The HTML for this is here:

```
    <div class="counter_wrap">

    <!-- Counter Title -->
        <h1>Countdown to Grand-Opening!</h1>

    <!-- Counter Title -->

    <!-- Counter Section -->
        <div class="numbers"><p class="days">23</p><p class="smallfont">Days</p></div>
        <div class="numbers"><p class="hours">19</p><p class="smallfont">Hours</p></div>
        <div class="numbers"><p class="minutes">7</p><p class="smallfont">Minutes</p></div>
        <div class="numbers"><p class="seconds">23</p><p class="smallfont">Seconds</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a problem:

```
var timer = setTimeout('countdown()', 1000);
```

Why just call it like:

```
var timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

The string and `eval` is really unnecessary. Also.

```
var timer = setTimeout(countdown(), 1000);
// is not the same as:
var timer = setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
```

In the first one you're scheduling the output of `countdown()` be called as a function. In the second one you're actually `countdown` (which is what you want).

Comment: That did it! Thanks. I can accept your answer in 10 minutes says Mr. Stack.